# @media tag not working for phtml file

Tags: html, css, magento

i want to give css for mobile view and tablet view. i have created media tag and wrote the code but its not working i have wrote

at top of the phtml file and wrote class name for which i have give css like below

```
<code>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"> //at top
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1000px)
{.numbertext
 {
   font-size: 50px;
   color: red;
 }
}
</code>
```

please help me how should i write to get correct output

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing a style tag.

It should be like this :

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1000px)
{
.numbertext
{
font-size: 50px;
color: red;
}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrapp your media queries inside the style tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
        .yourClass{

        }
    }
</style>
```